# Is there a way to prevent List View buttons appearing in Customer Portal?

Tags: customer-portal, list-view, list-button

If I create a List View button that is really only intended for my internal users, that List View button also seems to be appear in the Customer Portal.

For example, `Test Button` is valid for internal users but not portal users:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, right now there is no way to customize it on this level.
I can propose only to create Custom Visualforce page with "List View" functionality for Customers.